# SSH filesystem (sshfs) with indirect access

Tags: sshfs

Say I have ssh access to machine "foo":

```
me@local: ssh user1@foo
```

And from there i can access "bar":

```
user1@foo: ssh user2@bar
```

With this setup, is there any way I can use sshfs to mount in my local machine a directory located in "bar"?

I don't have administrative access in "foo", so I can't use sshfs to mount a directory there.

Comment: Is there no way to SSH directly into `bar`?

Comment: No, I can only access it through foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use a ProxyCommand to tell SSH to use "foo" as a "jump point" to access "bar".

You need to set up things so that you can access "bar" directly from your shell. Once you're able to `ssh bar` without having to explicitly log into "foo" first, sshfs should work transparently (and it does, I just tested it).

To accomplish this, add stuff like this to `.ssh/config`:

```
Host bar
   ProxyCommand ssh foo nc -q0 %h %p
```